# Use a template template parameter with CRTP in a Concept

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, c++-concepts

I want to write a `concept` that tests for inheritance from a base class.

My `Base` class is publicly inherited by `Derived` classes, using CRTP.

This code works fine:

```
#include <type_traits>
namespace NS
{
    template<typename D>
    class Base {
        // ...
    };

    class Derived : public Base<Derived>
    {
    public:
        constexpr Derived() = default;
        // ...
    };
}

template<typename D>
concept bool inheritsFromB() {
    return std::is_base_of<NS::Base<D>, D>::value;
}

template<inheritsFromB b>
void myFunct() {};

int main() {
    constexpr auto d = NS::Derived();
    using dType = typename std::decay<decltype(d)>::type;
    myFunct<dType>();
}
```

I hit a problem if I want to template `Derived`. Is this possible?

```
namespace NS
{
    template<typename D, typename T>
    class Base { ... };

    template<typename T>
    class Derived : public Base<Derived<T>, T>
    { // ...
      // probably some using declaration for T? 
    };
}

template<template <typename> class D>
concept bool inheritsFromB() {
    return std::is_base_of<NS::B<D<T>,T>, D<T>::value;
}

...
```

the obvious problem being that I have no `T` in my `concept` declaration.
Moreover, I'm pretty sure I can't declare

```
template<template <typename> class D, typename T> 
concept bool inheritsFromB() {
... 
}
```

<strike>because a `concept` requires one template parameter.</strike>

**Edit** - the [Working Paper P0121R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0121r0.pdf) lists in *section 8.3.5, p23*, `template<typename T, typename U> concept bool C3 = true;`. Consequently, wherever I read a `concept` can take only one parameter was either outdated, wrong, or I read it lacking care. **end edit**

Can I access the other type(s) `T` that I need here? Is there an alternative way (it seems to me like the template type `D` would carry the information of what it's type `T` is, but I also can't use `using T = typename D<T>::valueType;`, because I need the `T` to specific the type of `D<T>`...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the following trait should work:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace NS
{
    template <typename D, typename T>
    class Base {};    
    template <typename T>
    class Derived : public Base<Derived<T>, T> {};
}

namespace detail
{
    template <typename T, template <typename> typename D>
    std::true_type is_derived_from_base(const ::NS::Base<D<T>,T>*);
    std::false_type is_derived_from_base(void*);
}

template <typename T>
using is_derived_from_base = decltype(detail::is_derived_from_base(std::declval<T*>())); 

template <typename T>
concept bool inheritsFromB()
{
    return is_derived_from_base<T>{};
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e7277bad99ca57d) (without concepts)

Comment: Looks good - I nested the `detail` namespace inside `NS` and then moved the `using is_derived_from_base` declaration into `NS` also, such that my concept now uses `NS::is_derived_from_base`. Thanks for the answer!